# Where did I go wrong?

Tags: complex-analysis

> I'm trying to compute the harmonic conjugate of $u(x,y)=x-y$ on $\mathbb R^2$

Let $v$ be the harmonic conjugate of $u(x,y).$ Then $u_x=v_y\implies v_y=-1\implies v=y+\phi(x).$

Also, $u_y=-v_x\implies 1=\phi'(x)\implies\phi(x)=x+d\implies v=y+x+d$

Is it correct?

Comment: But $0!=1$. It's all fine! =) On the other hand, you want $c$ to be $x$ dependent, don't you? If $\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial y}=-1$ then $v=-y+C(x)$.

Comment: Hint: $(1+i)z=z+iz=x-y+i(x+y)$.

Comment: **How is this too localized?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that from $$u_x=1$$ $$u_y=-1$$ you get that $$v_x=1$$ $$v_y=1$$

It follows that $v(x,y)=y+C(x)$ and $v(x,y)=x+C_1(y)$ for each $y$, for some unknown $C,C_1$.

Subtract. What do you get?

**SPOILER**

> Then for every $x,y$, $$0=y-x+C(x)-C(y)$$ This means that $C(x)=x$ and $C(y)=y$.